# jQuery with ASP.NET WebForms for a poor old server dev

Tags: asp.net, jquery, webforms, jquery-1.3.2

OK, being a server developer, this Javascript voodoo on the ASP.NET page (based on a master page) rendered on the client is a bit too much for me, it seems :-)

I decided to try to use jQuery to handle some client-side enabling and disabling of UI elements.

I have two radio buttons (`rbnDoLimit` and `rbnDontLimit`), and three checkboxes (`months12`, `months24`, `months36`) - if I click on `rbnDoLimit`, I'd like to enable all three of them, if I click on `rbnDontLimit`, I like to clear and disable the three checkboxes. Seems simple enough, right?

So I downloaded and included jQuery 1.3.2 in my ASP.NET 3.5 webform - works OK, I can display an "alert" on the $(document).ready event.

My two radio buttons get rendered out in the page as:

```
<input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_rbnDontLimit" 
       type="radio" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$LimitMVD" 
       value="False" checked="checked" />
<input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_rbnDoLimit" 
       type="radio" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$LimitMVD" 
       value="True" />
```

and my three checkboxes as:

```
<span class="dcDetails"><input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_months12" 
      type="checkbox" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$months12" /></span>
<span class="dcDetails"><input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_months24" 
      type="checkbox" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$months24" /></span>
<span class="dcDetails"><input id="ctl01_cphContent_pnlBasicInfo_months36" 
      type="checkbox" name="ctl01$cphContent$pnlBasicInfo$months36" /></span>
```

I adorned them with a CSS class of `dcDetails` (which doesn't exist - but is intended to be used for selecting them in jQuery). The first thing I noticed is that the CSS class wasn't applied to my `<input>` elements as expected, but onto a `<span>` element around the `<input>`...... (the first mystery to me.....). Anyway.....

My first jQuery attempt looks like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        $("#<%= rbnDontLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $(".dcDetails").attr('disabled','false'); 
        },
        $("#<%= rbnDoLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $(".dcDetails").attr('disabled','true'); 
        });
</script>
```

No luck - I can click on the two radio buttons all I want - nothing happens. I assume this is because the `dcDetails` CSS class is on the `<span>` around the checkboxes, right?

OK - so it get a bit messier, but this ought to work!! Now I'm selecting the three checkboxes specifically, by their `ClientID` - this ought to be exact and get the right elements, I thought:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        $("#<%= rbnDontLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','false'); 
            $("#<%= months24.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','false'); 
            $("#<%= months36.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','false'); 
        },
        $("#<%= rbnDoLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','true'); 
            $("#<%= months24.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','true'); 
            $("#<%= months36.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','true'); 
        });
</script>
```

Again, no luck......

So what the heck am I missing?? All these great snazzy demos can't seem to help me understand why this isn't working - not even a bit.... I guess I'm missing something very basic, very fundamentals - but I just can't seem to figure out, what that is! :-)

Marc

**UPDATE:**
haven't had much luck yet :-( I stripped down my sample to a barebones HTML page - but I keep having this error over and over and over again, no matter which of the various tips I try:

Webpage error details

Message: Object doesn't support this property or method
Line: 3032
Char: 6
Code: 0
URI: file:///D:/projects/JQuery1/jquery-1.3.2.js

Almost seems to be an error deep inside jQuery....... any ideas?

**UPDATE 2:**
I'm beginning to think I'm doing something fundamentally wrong here.... I assumed that in the document.ready() function, I could hook up the click events on the two radio buttons. Am I missing something here? Would I need to create a function that I call from the radio button's client "on click" event instead? Whatever I'm trying to do, even in my HTML editor (TopStyle 4) - this error "object doesn't support this property or method" keeps popping up all the time - conveniently **neither** telling me which object it refers to, **nor** telling me what property or method is not supported........

Or am I doing something wrong trying to hook up two click event handler functions in the document.ready() ??

The scaled down, HTML only version is available at http://jquery.bluenose.ch/jquerydemo.html for anyone who might be interested - I expected to be able to click on the "Do Limit" radio button and have it disable the three checkboxes below it - no go :-(

Comment: Here's how to work around the SPAN issue - change

$("#<%= rbnDontLimit.ClientID %>").click(function()

to

$("#<%= rbnDontLimit.ClientID %> span").click(function()

Comment: or I think you can also specify just class instead of CssClass in the checkbox.

Comment: In the future use something like FireBug to help you debug and find the line that an error is occurring.

Comment: @rball: thanks for the tip - that's been one of the main problems I have with client-side voodoo - how on earth do I debug that?? ;-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I took a look at your example and there were some syntax issues.

Your example:

```
 $(document).ready(
    $('#rbnDontLimit').click(function() {
        $(".dcDetails :input").removeAttr('disabled');
    }),
    $("#rbnDoLimit").click(function() {
        $('.dcDetails :input').attr('disabled', 'true');
    }));
```

You were missing the "function (){" after the ready and its corresponding "}" at the end.
The comma between the to click events should have been a semicolon.
Remove the ":input" from the jQuery selectors.
This should work for you:

```
   $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#rbnDontLimit').click(function() {
            $(".dcDetails").removeAttr('disabled');
        });
        $("#rbnDoLimit").click(function() {
            $('.dcDetails').attr('disabled', true);
        });
    });
```

Comment: Yep, that's it ! :-) Thanks - I thought it was just something really small and silly - but I just couldn't see it. MANY THANKS !!

Comment: Wow, I didn't catch that...nice eye

Answer (score 1):

Try changing:

```
$("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','false')
```

to:

```
$("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','disabled')
```

and

```
$("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','true')
```

to:

```
$("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','')
```

Comment: There may be a better way, but I'm pretty sure that'll work /:

Comment: Doesn't seem to change anything at all, sorry ;-( As much as I click on the two radiobuttons, nothing happens..... the checkboxes stay there, same as always.....

Comment: In the event, add:

alert ($("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").length);

This will alert out the number of elements jQuery found that match your selector - could be the selector is matching nothing...

Comment: You might also try replacing $ with jQuery...sometimes other libraries (such as ASP.NET AJAX) overwrite it...

Comment: @Kieron: no luck, I'm not getting anywhere... the JS error says "object doesn't support property or method" - does the "radio" input element not have a ".click" method? Or is it called something else?

Comment: Ah, did you replace '$("#...' with 'jQuery("#...' yet?

Comment: Also, the click method is part of jQuery, not the input element.

Comment: About to shoot home, so one last thing - May be worth your time putting the debugger keyword above the executing code so you can inspect the elements in Visual Studio too...

Comment: Replacing every $ with jQuery has no effect - I am still getting the same error and nothing happens :-(

Comment: Thanks for all your help ! See gw's answer for the solution to the problem (syntax errors on my part)

Answer (score 0):

Use Kieron's answer and then...

```
$("#<%= rbnDontLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $(".dcDetails").attr('disabled','false'); 
}
```

could also be changed to:

```
$("#<%= rbnDontLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $(".dcDetails > :checkbox").attr('disabled','disabled'); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To disable a checkbox(any control), I use the following

```
$("#chkSomething").attr("disabled", "true")
```

To enable a checkbox(any control), I use the following

```
$("#chkSomething").removeAttr("disabled")
```

To answer your question,

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(
        $("#<%= rbnDontLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled"); 
            $("#<%= months24.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled"); 
            $("#<%= months36.ClientID %>").removeAttr("disabled"); 
        },
        $("#<%= rbnDoLimit.ClientID %>").click(function() {
            $("#<%= months12.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','true'); 
            $("#<%= months24.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','true'); 
            $("#<%= months36.ClientID %>").attr('disabled','true'); 
        });
</script>
```